# actions on google - Can't get askForDateTime to work

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Am I the only one who can't get the askForDateTime() helper to work or am I doing it wrong?

I defined a "newappointment" intent using dialogflow and the webhook handler is something like this:

```
function newAppointment(app) {
    app.askForDateTime('When appointment?', 'date?', 'hour');
}
```

The assistant seems to be unable to recognize the hour part.
I tried things like "today at 9", "9", "9PM", "at 9", "9 o'clock", ...

this is the result on the simulator:

[image: this is the result on the simulator]

Comment: Did you try "today at 9pm" as a single statement? In your screenshot it looks like they're separate.

Comment: It may be my fault. I restarted from scratch and it is now working. I may have a problem with timezone but need to investigate. Thank you Nick.